# Repo page after changing username

Tags: github

I am aware that web links to existing repositories will continue to work after changing username. Will the repo page get redirected also after changing username?

Comment: I don't have a source, but AFAIK the answer is no. (Btw, can't you try it out yourself with a dummy repo/account?)